# Exportar como PDF una selección en Excel usando VBA

Tags: excel, pdf, vba

Estoy tratando de exportar a PDF una selección específica usando Macros y no me sale. El código que estoy usando es:

```
Sub impreso_pedido()

  Sheets("IMPRESOS").Range("A11:E11").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
   fileName:="Macintosh HD:Users:giuseppe:Desktop:pedido.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
   IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
   From:=1, To:=1, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Como resultado no hace mucho, me genera un documento pdf en blanco en el escritorio y ya está.

Algún alma bondadosa que me pueda ayudar?

Saludos a todos.

Answer (score 1):

¿Probaste con 
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False
?

Busqué acá

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073888/vba-script-that-saves-excel-range-as-pdf

y sólo encontré eso cómo diferencia entre el post y tu propuesta.

Answer (score 0):

modifica la parte de fileName. Los **':'** en un path solo se admiten para identificar el nombre del dispositivo. C:... Z:...

```
'Esta parte es la que da problemas
fileName:="Macintosh HD:Users:giuseppe:Desktop:pedido.pdf"

'Con este cambio me crea perfectamente el pdf. 
fileName:="pedido.pdf"
```

Corrige el path y si estás usando un mac no utilices '\' sino '/'

```
fileName:="D:\MyProyect\pdf\pedido.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sub BotonPDF()
Dim CeldaNombre As Range
Dim NombreArchivo As String
Dim RutaArchivo As String

```
Set CeldaNombre = Hoja1.Range("A11")
If CeldaNombre.Value = "" Then
    NombreArchivo = Format(Now, "ddmmyyyy_hhmmss") & ".pdf"
Else
    NombreArchivo = Mid(CeldaNombre.Value, 1, InStr(1, CeldaNombre.Value, " ", vbTextCompare) - 1) & _
                    "_" & Format(Now, "ddmmyyyy_hhmmss") & ".pdf"
End If

RutaArchivo = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & _
              Application.PathSeparator & _
              NombreArchivo
              
'---
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim NumeroDeFilasDeLaTabla As Long
NumeroDeFilasDeLaTabla = Hoja1.ListObjects("Cotizacion").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
Hoja1.Cells(18 + NumeroDeFilasDeLaTabla + 2, 1).Value = "ECHO POR JOSE LUIS BEREA "
Hoja1.Cells(18 + NumeroDeFilasDeLaTabla + 2, 1).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
'---

Hoja1.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                          Filename:=RutaArchivo, _
                          Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                          IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                          OpenAfterPublish:=True
                          
Hoja1.Cells(18 + NumeroDeFilasDeLaTabla + 2, 1).Value = ""
Hoja1.Cells(18 + NumeroDeFilasDeLaTabla + 2, 1).Font.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Hoja1.Range("A4").Select
```

End Sub

USA ESTE

Comment: Pulsá en [edit] y describí cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Leé [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.